# In MYSQL 6.2 Workbench, can an item be recorded in 1 table but be stored in another table (look-up table)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a MySQL 6.0 database for a system like a forum. In this system, users can add keywords to 'tag' their posts and comments. Can this be done?

Comment: Sorry @HoboSapiens I meant MySQL workbench 6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do what you want with triggers, or with application logic in whatever language you are using for your middle Tier